# NPM command interupted by Windows displaying version

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, create-react-app, npx

I've a problem. Everytime i try to use a npx/npm command, Windows seems to stop it and display windows version :

[npm/npx error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1z1e.png)

Or into an already created project :

[npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wHoz.png)

Here are my node and npm version :
[Npm/npx node version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgh4q.png)

Can't do anything. Tried the solution [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) literally every command.

Comment: There is no error and windows is not stopping anything.

Comment: There is no error as it's not displayed. The command is launched then the prompt display the windows version message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize your command prompt you can either edit the environment variable or in command line using `set prompt`, type this command in command line `help prompt` it will display this

```
Changes the cmd.exe command prompt.

PROMPT [text]

  text    Specifies a new command prompt.

Prompt can be made up of normal characters and the following special codes:

  $A   & (Ampersand)
  $B   | (pipe)
  $C   ( (Left parenthesis)
  $D   Current date
  $E   Escape code (ASCII code 27)
  $F   ) (Right parenthesis)
  $G   > (greater-than sign)
  $H   Backspace (erases previous character)
  $L   < (less-than sign)
  $N   Current drive
  $P   Current drive and path
  $Q   = (equal sign)
  $S     (space)
  $T   Current time
  $V   Windows version number
  $_   Carriage return and linefeed
  $$   $ (dollar sign)

If Command Extensions are enabled, the PROMPT command supports
the following additional formatting characters:

  $+   zero or more plus sign (+) characters depending upon the
       depth of the PUSHD directory stack, one character for each
       level pushed.

  $M   Displays the remote name associated with the current drive
       letter or the empty string if the current drive is not a network
       drive.
```

In your case I would suggest this command `set PROMPT=$P$_$G` . Try out different prompts choose which is preferable to you.